# How to move an image in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Help on moving elements on the canvas. How to add images on the canvas and make them move by pressing buttons from the keyboard

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37)
    {
     launcher.dir = 'left';
    }
}, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 37)
    {
     launcher.dir = '';
    }
}, false); 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 39)
    {
     launcher.dir = 'right';
    }
}, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 39)
    {
     launcher.dir = '';
    }
}, false); 
left_btn.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    launcher.dir = '';
});
right_btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    launcher.dir = 'right';
});
```

Comment: Just use drawImage instead of fillRect. Be sure your images are already loaded before starting your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move a "shape" on the canvas in two ways:

- Just recalculate the absolute coordinates of the shape each frame.
- Use transformations (a common way to do that in CG). In your case you would need a `translation`. (see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-translate-tutorial/) To really undestand how to use that, It might additionally be usefull to read something about the state-stack http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transformation-state-stack-tutorial/

Comment: I'm able to move the shape, but how to move the image instead of the shape??

Comment: Imagine you draw the image at the coordinates [10,10]. If you call ctx.translate(10, 0) before ctx.drawImage(10, 10) it should be moved to [20,10]. Transformations apply to everything that will be drawn on the canvas, not only shapes. So you just need to call translate in each frame to move the image. And to prevent, that translate() will be applied to everything else that you draw, use ctx.save() and ctx.restore() as explained in the linked example for a state stack.